# collection view showing less number of cell in cellForItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

I have a collection view with a array of 5 items as given below:

```
var photos = [String]()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 self.photos = ["background", "living", "bedroom", "dining","bathroom"]
}
```

In the collection view

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("total no of photos are",photos.count)
        return photos.count

    }
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = photocollview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell10", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell


        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0


        let str = photos[indexPath.row]

        print("str is",str)

}
```

The number of items in section in the collection view is showing 5 but in the cellforitemat

the str is showing only 3values when printed.

What could the issue be?

Comment: No `return cell` ? Also, how many "space" do you have? If you can show only 3 cells, not all indexPaths will be called in `cellForItemAt`.

Comment: return cell is there.how to see all the cells?

Comment: What size is the cell? What size is the collectionView? Scroll and they will trigger it? Imagine that you have a cell the size of the collectionView which is the size of the screen. So cellForItemAt will be triggered only to show the first cell. It's all about optimization of ressources, call cellForItemAt only on demand.

Answer (score 1):

call also return, maybe its helpful.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = photocollview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell10", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
   cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
   cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
   let str = photos[indexPath.row]
   print("str is",str)
   return cell
}
```